# how to know which service restarted every one min

Tags: linux, shell-script, services

from the /var/log/message we see the following

```
Jan 08 06:01:01 kafka1 systemd: Started Session 37735 of user root.
Jan 08 06:01:01 kafka1 systemd: Starting Session 37735 of user root.
```

how to know which service is it ?

**note from the log we can saw that service restarted every one min**

Comment: given the regularity, it's likely that there's a root-owned cron job on the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those messages are created automatically each time any user logs in; if you want to remove them, you can see how to do it in the Red Hat support page:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1564823

Namely:

> To suppress these log entries in /var/log/messages, create a discard filter with rsyslog, e.g., run the following command:
>
> ```
> echo 'if $programname == "systemd" and ($msg contains "Starting Session" or $msg contains "Started Session" or $msg contains "Created slice" or $msg contains "Starting user-" or $msg contains "Starting User Slice of" or $msg contains "Removed session" or $msg contains "Removed slice User Slice of" or $msg contains "Stopping User Slice of") then stop' >/etc/rsyslog.d/ignore-systemd-session-slice.conf
> ```
>
> Then restart the rsyslog service:
>
> ```
> systemctl restart rsyslog
> ```